# [Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually

Tags: android, linux, cordova

Im using Cordova in Linux mint 17

I installed android sdk , cordova , android studio , nodejs 4

problem is here
when i wanna build app in codova and run this on terminal :

sudo cordova build android

it shows

```
Running command: /home/tnt/hello12/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/tnt/hello12/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/tnt/hello12/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
```

I put this code

```
 export HOME="/home/tnt"
    export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/android/sdk/tools"
    export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$HOME/android/sdk/platform-tools"
    export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$PATH"
    export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"
    export ANT_HOME="/usr/share/ant"
    export PATH="$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH"
    export ANDROID_HOME="/home/tnt/android/sdk/tools"
```

on  my

```
/home/tnt/.bash_profile  
/home/tnt/.bashrc
/home/tnt/.profile  
/root/.bash_profile  
/root/.bashrc
/root/.profile
```

but it wont works

Comment: Don't call cordova by using sudo. If the problem is still there, follow these docs: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/platforms/android/index.html

Comment: i used this Android Platform Guide but it didnt solved

Comment: If you have an access denied during cordova build, then you have installed cordova by using sudo. That is a good way to run into problems. Install cordova and your project again, but don't use sudo.

Comment: are you sure ??? is this error just becouse of sudo???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think its necessary to add everything into path.Just add the `JAVA_HOME` , `ANDROID_HOME` and `ANT_HOME` to path and point out the corresponding `bin directory` as:

## For android studio

add this into your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
1.export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android/studio
2.export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin
```

you can do the same for `Ant.`

## For java jdk

add this into your /etc/profile file:

```
1.JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk
2.JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
3.PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
4.export JAVA_HOME
5.export JRE_HOME
6.export PATH
```

Now in your terminal, type `echo $PATH` and make sure all the environment variables are added to the PATH!

Comment: is it ok? /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

Comment: Yes ,I believe. But still, to be double sure, open up your terminal  and type in locate jdk and hit enter.It will show the related paths which will give you rough ideas about the possible jdk path! It is generally recommended that you manually download the latest version of jdk from the oracle site,extract it and paste it inside /usr/local/ directory!

Comment: There is no /bin inside the SDK directories, nor has ever been to my recall. Double check that

Comment: i updated the answer, I typed SDK by mistake there :)

Comment: Hello. Somehow I allways get a `:` colon at the end of the `echo $PATH` causing the error `No such file or directory`. The error is not correlated with your code..

Answer (score 7):

You should edit /etc/sudoers with

```
sudo visudo
```

At the end of the file enter:

```
Defaults    env_keep +="ANDROID_HOME"
```